# Understanding Eloquent Javascript's Reduce function

Tags: javascript, reduce

In *Eloquent Javascript*, the author asks the reader to write a function `countZeroes`, which takes an array of numbers as its argument and returns the amount of zeroes that occur in it as another example for the use of the *reduce* function.

I know

- that the concept of the reduce function is to take an array and turn it to a single value.
- what the ternary operator is doing which is the essential portion of the function.

I don't know

- where the arguments for the *counter* function are coming from.

From the book:

```
function countZeroes(array) {
  function counter(total, element) { // Where are the parameter values coming from?
    return total + (element === 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return reduce(counter, 0, array);
}
```

Earlier example from the text:

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
 forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}
```

Comment: I've written a course on Codeacademy on this topic. It teaches the basics of higher value functions such as map, reduce, sort etc.

https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-advanced-en-eQcHT/0/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the code, there is only one possible answer: Since you the function `counter` is only referenced once when passed to `reduce()`, reduce must thus provide the arguments to the function.

### How reduce works

Here is a visualization of how reduce works. You need to read the diagrom from top to bottom, `/` and `\` denote which parameters (below) are passed to the `counter()` function above.

```
                   return value of reduce()
                   /
                 etc ...
                /
            counter
           /       \
       counter      xs[2]
      /       \
  counter      xs[1]
 /       \
0         xs[0]
```

`counter()` is initially provided with `0` (after all, the initial total amount of seen zeroes when you haven't processed any elements yet is just zero) and the first element.

That `0` is increased by one if the first element of the array is a zero. The new total after having seen the first element is then returned by `counter(0, xs[0])` to the `reduce()` function. As long as elements are left, it then passes this value as new pending total to the `counter()` function, along with the next element from your array: `xs[1]`.

This process is repeated as long as there are elements in the array.

### Mapping this concept to the code

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
 forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}
```

As can be seen in the illustration, `0` is passed through `base` to the function initially, along with `element`, which denotes `xs[0]` on the first "iteration" within the `forEach` construct. The resulting value is then written back to `base`.

As you can see in the visualization, `0` is the left parameter to the function `counter()`, whose result is then passed as left parameter to `counter()`. Since `base/total` acts as the left paramter within the `forEach` construct, it makes sense to write that value back to `base/total`, so the previous result will be passed to `counter()/combine()` again upon the next iteration. The path of `/`s is the "flow" of `base/total`.

### Where `element` comes from

From [chapter 6 of Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html), here is the implementation of `forEach()` (In the comment, I have substituted the call to `action` with the eventual values.)

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]); // <-- READ AS: base = counter(base, array[i]);
}
```

`action` denotes a function, that is called within a simple `for` loop for every element, while iterating over `array`.

In your case, this is passed as `action` to `forEach()`:

```
function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
}
```

It is the anonymous function defined upon each call to `reduce()`. So `element` is "really" `array[i]` once for each iteration of the `for`.

Comment: I really appreciate your diagram as well. The only part I'm missing now is how the individual element is being pulled out of the array. The big picture makes perfect sense, however I want to understand where exactly the "element" is being pulled from the array.

Comment: @AMK I have added that to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Ok, got it now thank's to both of you. I see how the iteration of forEach is providing the individual array element.

Comment: @AMK You're welcome. Sidenote: I have edited your question so visitors aren't greeted by a "big wall of text", I have included the book's title (which is relevant) into the title, which also makes it immediately clear, that the question is about JavaScript). Also, you don't need to include "Thanks" in your question, that way we get to answers sooner ;)

Answer (score 8):

the function `counter` is passed as the first parameter of `reduce` when called in your first block of code. Within the `reduce` function, the first parameter is known as `combine`. This is then called with parameters `base` and `element` which are the mysterious arguments you are seeking!

So the tricky bit, is that the function is not executed where it is defined and named, but passed as a parameter to the reduce function, which then executes it.

### Edit: elaboration

[image: logic flow]

so... the function is defined and named (at point 1), then the definition is passed, without the name to another function (at point 2) along with variables (I called i and ii) where it picks up the name of the first parameter (at point 3) before being called (at point 4) along with the other parameters

### edit: further elaboration

I updated the image, to better explain the elements coming from the array.

So `i` is easier to follow, being created as `0` when the `reduce` function is called, and allocated the name `base` as a parameter, before being reassigned as the result of the `counter`/`combine` function, which returns the `base` with a possible increment.

`ii` starts life as an array passed to `countZeroes`, and is then passed along the chain until it is iterated over by a `forEach` loop, which extracts a single `element` and operates the `combine` function on it (along with `base`).

Comment: Thank you Billy, it's slightly clearer now, but I'm still having a hard time seeing how it's working from line to line. Where is the "element" argument for the anonymous function coming from? Would you be able to give a bit more of a line by line breakdown?

Comment: Billy, thank you again. This is definitely helping. How is the individual element being pulled out of the array for the anonymous function parameter?

Comment: @AMK For that, you would need to consult the implementation of that particular `forEach()` function, which is probably where the function itself is introduced the first time.

Comment: phant0m, yes the parameters for the forEach function are an array and an "action", which in this case is the anonymous function. So, I'm still not sure where that the "element" parameter is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` method passes the parameters in. Somewhere in the source code of the `reduce` function is probably something like this:

```
function reduce(iterator, memo, collection) { // in your example, iterator here is your counter function
    …
    // while looping through the collection you passed in
    memo = iterator(memo, collection[i], i); // it calls your counter function and
                                             // passes the total and the current array
                                             // element as well as the current index,
                                             // then stores the result to be passed in
                                             // with the next array element
    …
    return memo;
}
```

### Addendum

Maybe this will help illustrate better ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMNjf/1/)):

```
// very simple reduce implementation
function reduce(iterator, memo, collection) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        memo = iterator(memo, collection[i], i);
    }
    return memo;
}

zeroes = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1];
function counter(total, element) { return total + (element === 0 ? 1 : 0); }

alert(reduce(counter, 0, zeroes));
```