# Higher order functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am working through Eloquent Javascript. The function *count* takes an array and a test function (*equals(x)*) as arguments, and returns the amount of elements in the array for which the test function returned true.

I understand the broad way that these functions are working, and that logically the *total* argument to the anonymous function passed to reduce has a value of zero.

Can someone help me to see where the value for total is coming from specifically though? I want to have a clearer picture in my mind.

```
function count(test, array) {
  return reduce(function(total, element) { // Where is the value for total coming from?
    return total + (test(element) ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0, array);
}

function equals(x) {
  return function(element) {return x === element;};
}

function countZeroes(array) {
  return count(equals(0), array);
}
```

Reduce Function from earlier:

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}
```

forEach Function from earlier:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: `base` is being passed as the `total` argument, as far as I can tell. `base` here is 0, so `total` is 0 in that evaluation.

Comment: Yes, logically I can see that. I'm just not clear on where the value is coming from specifically.

Comment: This seems to be virtually the same as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203511/understanding-eloquent-javascripts-reduce-function). What are the differences here to your last question?

Comment: Yes, I drew out everything from yesterday again this morning and it was pretty clear. This was the following code after it. I guess I'm just struggling with seeing how the lines are running when using functions as parameters.

Comment: So it would seem, yes, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question of course :P I think it would be best, if you described your line of thought how the functions interact first, before we go about answering this question.

Comment: phant0m, I see that reduce is being passed an anonymous function rather than the combine function. And, inside the anonymous function you use the equals(x) function. I just can't wrap my head around the exact command that is the framework for the "total" value.

Comment: @phant0m Wow, ASCII art explanation ftw. AMK could you explain where exactly you are having difficulties following the explanation? I bet it would also help if you used Firebug or something similar to step through the code.

Comment: @phant0m Ah alright. It seems the problem is then that AMK is having trouble understanding the name `combine` that is used for the anonymous function inside reduce.

Comment: I'm am fairly new to this site and development in general. If it would be easier, can we chat rather than posting?

Comment: (hoping this triggers a chat invite) edit: not yet, maybe I can create a room, still writing on my answer though, bear with me

Comment: so are these two function calls essentially equal to each other: combine(base,element) and function(total,element)?

Comment: @AMK The first is a function call. The second is a function *definition*.

Comment: I guess what I like to do (I'm trying to teach myself) is compare my function blueprint with the function that is running the values. So, that's what I was trying to do here.

Comment: Asad, but, they are equivalent correct?

Comment: I really appreciate all the help, but what I'm trying to understand is, what the blueprint for function(total,element) is?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by blueprint.

Comment: What is the exact command you read that tells you 0 is the value of total? I know that total === base === 0, but where is the line that specifically implies that.

Comment: Inside `count()`: `reduce(function {...}, 0, array`. See that zero there? That gets passed to `reduce` and is there known as `base`, which makes for the initial value of `total` upon the first iteration within `forEach`.

Comment: Yes, I see 0 as the base argument in reduce. I will just have to continue looking at this I guess.

Comment: ;) I have "unwrapped" the last function calls in my answer, so you can see what the code boils down to. Trying to understand everything at once is virtuous, but it may be better to try to understand `reduce` by itself at first. reduce(left) always does the following: `(...((((a + x1) + x2) + x3) + x4) + ...) + xlast`, but `+` is not necessarily the mathematical plus function, but any function that takes two arguments and returns one of the same type. `a` denotes the initial element. For instance, if you wanted to sum a list of numbers, you could use: `reduce(plus, 0, numbers)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19030/discussion-between-amk-and-phant0m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 arguments you passed to reduce were:

```
{
    combine:function(total, element){...},
    base:0,
    array:array
}
```

The function then takes `base` and passes it to the `combine` function as the `total` argument:

```
base = combine(base, element);
```

Basically, what is happening here is that for each element in the array you just passed (as the 3rd argument `array`) the function takes the argument `base` and increments it using the anonymous function you have provided (which first checks if the element passes `test`). Finally, after it has iterated over all the elements, it returns the final value of `base`.

Perhaps this will help explain:

```
function count(test, testarray) {
  var anon = function(total, element) { // Where is the value for total coming from?
    return total + (test(element) ? 1 : 0);
  };
  //now anon is a function.
  return reduce(anon, 0, testarray);
}
```

Let us look at the function invocation and definition closely:

```
return   reduce(anon   , 0   , testarray);
                  |      |     |
                  v      v     v
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
    combine;    //the function that is passed in as the first argument
    base;       //the number that is passed in as the second argument
    array;      //the array that is passed in as the third argument
```

The *values* of each of `anon`,`0`, and `testarray`, get passed into the function. Within the function, their values can be accessed by the parameter names in the function definition.

Comment: That is what I assumed. Thank you for verifying.

Answer (score 3):

> I see that reduce is being passed an anonymous function rather than the combine function

That is not really true. The anonymous function *is* the `combine` function.

### `combine(base, element)` vs `function(total, element)`

> these two function calls essentially equal to each other: combine(base,element) and function(total,element)?

No, they're completely different things.

The former a function call, to a function referenced by `combine`.
The second, however, evaluates to a new function value. In the case of:

```
reduce(function(total, element) {...}, ...);
```

`reduce()` is being passed a function value, what this means is, that a *new function* is **created**, a function that accepts two parameters (denoted by `total` and `element`). This function is then passed to `reduce`.

---

Let me recycle my visualization from yesterday. It is important to realize, that this does not only apply to *your case*, but it applies to *every* embodiment of the *reduce(left)* concept.

```
                   return value of reduce()
                   /
                 etc ...
                /
            combine    
           /       \
       combine      xs[2]
      /       \
  combine      xs[1]
 /       \
0         xs[0]
```

Of course, this only shows *what* happens, not the *how* and I think in your case you're asking for *how*. Just keep this visualization in mind to see what the result is going to do.

### Substituting functions

To make it more clear what is going on, I'm going to gradually substitute the functions that are being passed around.

**Start of the program:**

```
function countZeroes(array) {
  return count(equals(0), array);
}
```

`equals(0)` (you could call this a form of currying) evaluates to a function, that is being passed to `count()`.

This results in basically the following `count()` function:

```
function count(array) {
  return reduce(function(total, element) { // Where is the value for total coming from?
    return total + (0 == element ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0, array);
}
```

From here, we can extract the `combine` argument:

```
function combine(total, element) { // Where is the value for total coming from?
    return total + (0 == element ? 1 : 0);
}
```

That is the function, that is used within the reduce function:

```
function reduce(base = 0, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}
```

`reduce(0, array)` is called from the `count()` function. The function that is passed to `forEach` could now be rewritten like this, taking into our account implementation of `combine`:

```
function reduce(base = 0, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = base + (0 == element ? 1 : 0);
  });
  return base;
}
```

Keep in mind, that `base` represents our `total`.

As our final step, we take into account what `forEach()` does.

```
function reduce(base = 0, array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    base = base + (0 == array[i] ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return base;
}
```

So this is what `count()` essentially looks like, all calls unwrapped:

```
function count(array) {
  var base = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    base = base + (0 == array[i] ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return base;
}
```