# what does higher-order function mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

javascript book "eloquent javascript"

```
function negate(func) {
return function(x) {
return !func(x);
 };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

someone explain it and as title of question says what is higher-order function, what does this code do ?

Comment: a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212940/higher-order-functions-javascript

Comment: Is your question what a higher order function is or what this specific function is doing? I think the function name and the following application already explains what it is doing, doesn't it? What a higher order function is, is explained on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_function.

Comment: i dont understand this function can u explain it ?

Comment: http://javascript.github.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When most people think of functions they accept objects or values as parameters and similarly return an object or value, such as `function addTwoNumbers(int x, int y)`.

In mathematics and computer science, a "higher-order function" is just like any other function, except that in addition to arguments that are values it can also accept a function as an argument.

...that's all a higher-order function is, really :)

In the example you posted, `negate` is a higher-order function because it has a parameter `func` which is a function (or rather, assigned to a function).

`negate` goes further: it doesn't merely call `func` and negate its result, instead it returns an anonymous function (that's the inner `return function(x)` bit).

So the `isNotNaN` variable then has the type (and value) of that earlier anonymous function.

Comment: where is this isNan coming from

Comment: @raziq: It's a built-in function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 0):

Higher-order function is a function that:

- Take one or more functions as input.
- Give another function as output.

What does your code do? it negates the function isNan (to isNotNan). It accept a function (isNan), and then output the negation (isNotNan). It's just that simple.

Comment: The function does not return the negation of the argument; it returns a function that returns the negation of the argument.

Comment: that's what i'm trying to say. It returns the isNotNan function.