# can this iteration be done with some nicer method?

Tags: javascript

Here is my initial solution to an study question regarding filling an object with items from an array...
But it seems like there should be a nicer solution. I read where "for... in" is not the proper way, but isn't there some nicer method I'm forgetting?

```
var doubler = function(arr) // fills object with numbers and their doubled value
{
    var my_obj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        my_obj[arr[i]] = arr[i]*2;     
    }
console.log(my_obj);
}

doubler([5,7,2,3,4,7])
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for improvements of an existing working code; it probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Aleks, what's supposed to be off-topic about that? The code in the question only illustrates the type of problem to be solved while Alnitak's answer provides the necessary steps.

Comment: The intent was not "does this code work?". It was "what new method do I study to take it to the next level".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function doubler(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(o, n) {
        o[n] = n * 2;  // adds required key and value to object
        return o;      // returns filled object
    }, {} );           // start with an empty object
}
```

`reduce` takes an array, and an initial value (`{}`), and performs some operation *in turn* on each value of the array and the result of the previous iteration (where a[0] and `{}` are used for the first iteration).

I'm slightly abusing it here by causing side effects (the assignment to the object) and just taking the initial object (`o == {}`) and returning the same (modified) object in each iteration.

A more idiomatic usage of `reduce` would be this:

```
function addUp(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(running_total, n) {
        return running_total + n;
    }, 0);  // 0 is actually the default value
}
```

Comment: that's the funky stuff I was talking about. Now I have to go see what those curly brackets are about at the end

Comment: @dwilbank I already just added some comments that should explain that - they're the initial value of `o`

Comment: @dwilbank FWIW, this is _probably_ not the fastest code in the world, but I do love those "functional programming" style methods on arrays :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to find a clear and complete tutorial on reduce. This is the best one so far? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203511/understanding-eloquent-javascripts-reduce-function

Comment: @dwilbank not really a good example because that's not the standard version of `reduce`.  I've added more explanation above.

Comment: Makes it a little easier, but line 3 is still tripping me up. I'm not seeing how "o" becomes the name of the object.

Comment: @dwilbank simply because that's the name of the parameter in the inner helper function - `reduce` will call that function with _four_ parameters, although I'm only using two.  The first parameter is the result of the previous iteration, i.e. the `return o` from the _previous_ pass.  On the first pass, the initial value (`{}`) is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and fast. I'd only recommend to cache the arr.length:

```
for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++)
```

and maybe the double lookup:

```
var item = arr[i];
my_obj[item] = item*2;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I like always declaring a variable for the current array element:

```
for(/*...*/){
   var x = arr[i];
   /*...*/
}
```

Its not a big deal but it save me from typing arr[i] over and over. Other than that, your current code is perfectly fine and maybe the only thing other thing to change would be minor performance improvements like caching the array length.

That said, one thing you could consider is using an iterator function instead of a for loop:

```
arr.forEach(function(x, i){
   my_obj[x] = x*2;
});
```

This has the advantage of automatic creating lexically scoped loop variables and you don't have to reference the array more than once (useful if its an expression instead of just a variable reference).

The most important caveat to this approach is that you can't use break, continue and return for control flow like you could in a regular loop. Additionally, there is a small performance penalty to calling the extra functions and some old browsers don't support the array iteration methods as builtins so you need to use a shim or library function instead.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to go study forEach!

Comment: @dwilbank: my the way, most Javascript libraries (underscore, etc) should include these iterator functions so you shouldn't have to implement them yourself.

Comment: ah - I'm seeing how it is sorting things however it likes, instead of keeping the order of the array. Valuable lesson though.

Comment: @dwilbank: what are you talking about? the forEach method should iterate over the array keys in order...